# Listar ultimo registro insertado en Mysql c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito sacar el último dato insertado dependiendo de una búsqueda.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDispositivos.Rows)
{
  string dispositivo = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
  //Aqui hago la consulta dependiendo del usuario en el ciclo:
  bd.ejecutarConsulta("SELECT dispositivo,latitud,longitud FROM dispositivos WHERE dispositivo='"+dispositivo+"'");
}
```

Como se han trazado muchas rutas en la tabla con ese dispositivo, solo quiero sacar el último dato que se insertó del mismo.

Answer (score 3):

Para saber cuál es el último registro insertado tienes dos opciones:

1. Crear un campo autoincremental en MySQL, como por ejemplo:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE table_name
   (
       id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
   )
   ```
2. Crear un campo de tipo date.

Si usas la primera opción, haces la búsqueda teniendo en cuenta que el id sea el mayor que cumple las condiciones de tu búsqueda (el dispositivo).

Si usas la segunda opción, haces la busqueda teniendo en cuenta que el date sea el mayor que cumple las condiciones de tu búsqueda (el dispositivo).

Comment: tengo ambos campos `id` y `fecha` pero como se cual es el ultimo `id`?

Comment: si el campo id es autoincremental el ultimo sera el de mayor valor, lo mismo con la fecha, si guardas en la fecha el valor Datetime.Now (por ejemplo), sera el que la fecha sea mayor tambien.

Answer (score 2):

Partamos de la base que ese metodo que muestras en el codigo es incorrecto, NUNCA debes armar una query concatenendo los valores en un string, tienes que usar parametros.

Ademas el codigo deberia retornar algo si es un SELECT, ya sea una lista, coleccion o datatable con los registros que obtienes del select

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDispositivos.Rows)
{
    string dispositivo = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    DataTable dt = bd.ObtenerDispositivos(dispositivo);

    //resto codigo
}



public DataTable ObtenerDispositivos(string dispositivo)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))  
    {  
        string query = "SELECT dispositivo,latitud,longitud FROM dispositivos WHERE dispositivo = @dispositivo";  

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dispositivo", dispositivo);  

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);    
        da.Fill(dt);  
    } 

    return dt;
}
```

como veras la idea es indicar el dispositivo y no el select para asi poder definir el parametro de la consulta

Answer (score 2):

Bueno la consulta que te ayuda con lo que necesitas es

```
SELECT TOP 1 dispositivo,latitud,longitud FROM dispositivos WHERE dispositivo = @dispositivo ORDER BY id DESC
```

Tal como dice @LeandroTuttini no concatenes string y valores, ocupa parametros